# Element type is invalid error using react-native and react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

I am creating an app in react-native and I have an error while using the drawer navigator and I can't seem to find out why this error is here.

the error is:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `DrawerView`.
```

it has something to do with the drawer navigation I have:

```
const AppStack = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {... props} /> } >
        <Drawer.Screen name="Map" component={MapScreen} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

but I just can't find out what exactly the problem is.

I have imported everything using the documentation so that is all correct.

This is the MapScreen Const:

```
const MapScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    return(
      <>
        <Map/>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} style={styles.drawerButton}/>
        <View style={styles.mapDrawerOverlay} />
      </>
    );
  };
```

and the `DrawerContent` is another file with everything inside the drawer navigator.

is there anyone who knows what this error can be?

Comment: Do you have a component called 'DrawerView' ?

Answer (score 2):

Check your @react-navigation/native and @react-navigation/drawer lib version they should have same version

Comment: I have the same issue. Versions :"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2", How do I downgrade drawer version?

Comment: same versions didn't solve the issue

Comment: @NightOwl
 if your using yarn you can first remove package and then add it like  yarn add package-name@version . npm is also the same

Comment: @AlbertMunichMar , check dependent library